# Overlay in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, intersection

I'm new to QGIS. I have constituency maps in India and block maps from 2001 census. Each constituency usually consists of a few blocks, but in some cases, a part of a block may belong to one constituency and another part to a different constituency.

I want QGIS to spit out the block-constituency polygons. For example, if block X belongs to constituency 1 and 2, I want two different polygons- X1 and X2, to be the output (I also require the area of the resultant polygons).

I tried the intersect command in overlay operations, but it seems to me that only the blocks are being shown, not the potentially smaller 'polygons'.

Does anyone know if intersect is indeed the right command to use here?

Comment: Could you please point out what overlay type you need to do ? http://pages.geo.wvu.edu/~elmes/geog350/Images/unit%2014%20Dia%202.jpg Intersect can be seen as (A AND B) in boolean, i.e keep only the common parts. I suppose you are looking for (A OR B) type ? > See Union then.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear for me, but try Clip or Intersection with different input/clip layer combinations. Maybe that can help.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can go for identity command.

Comment: It would be better if your answer provides a bit more detail (think a couple of paragraphs). Typically it would explain "how and why".